# How to add a reminder to a specific list and time via Siri

Tags: ios, siri, reminders

I can say " Add `call friend` to my Work list " and Siri will add that reminder to the specific reminder list `WORK`. However, if I imply any time, it will add it as a calendar entry.
Yet when I say " remind me to call friend on Thursday ", Siri will add the reminder on that day and at 9AM ...

But I would like to choose my own date and time for reminders while specifying which reminder list it goes in, how can I accomplish this ?

**EDIT**

I managed to find this method :

- Me : Remind me to call friend on thursday at 11am
- **Siri** : Here is your reminder, shall I create it ?
- Me : Move it to my *name* list

And then the reminder is moved to your specific list. However, I would rather avoid having to do this longwinded method, is there a way to skip step 2 and combine them all in one sentence ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it!

> Add "**list name**" reminder "**new item**" on "**date and time**"

Example: "Add activities reminder basketball practice on friday at 2pm."

Odd and slightly backwards syntax but works!

Comment: Perfect !! Haha how did you even think of that !!

Comment: I searched, combined, an tried a couple hundred different ways until siri was happy!  I have used this method half a dozen times since. Really useful.