# Siri: How to add an item to specific Reminders list AND set a reminder time?

Tags: ios, siri, reminders

**TL;DR**: Is there a way for Siri to create an item in a specific list, and add a timed reminder to it?

---

iOS 9 Siri is able to  add an item to a specific Reminders list in this fashion:

> Hey Siri; Add bread to my shopping list

However, I am struggling to find a 'syntax' that will add an item to a list, ***and*** set a timed reminder. Here is one example of my attempts:

> Hey Siri; Add book laundry time to my todo list and remind me in one hour

Siri doesn't seem to understand the "latter part" about the timed reminder. It also happens that that Siri will not place it in the correct list, but instead interpret the whole sentence as the string content of a reminder placed in the Inbox.

Comment: How about "Set reminder for 9am, get bread' ?

Comment: @Tetsujin That will not assign it to a specific list.

Comment: I don't think you can do 2 separate things at the same time; I've never had luck doing that.  I've been able to do 2 of the same things at the same time (Create list named groceries and add butter).  You might have to break those up into multiple statements.

Comment: You could possibly try "hey Siri, add bread to my shopping list and remind me at 9am"

Comment: @user2277872 Unfortunately didn't work, but good suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this question for the sentence structure you need to use to achieve this:

[How to add a reminder to a specific list and time via Siri](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110174/how-to-add-a-reminder-to-a-specific-list-and-time-via-siri)

> Add "**list name**" reminder "**new item**" on "**date and time**"
>
> Example: *"Add activities reminder basketball practice on friday at 2pm."*

Comment: Great job finding it

Comment: Okay, that syntax was super weird but it works. Thanks! :D

Comment: Yeah, it takes some getting used to and I would never have stumbled across it without finding that answer - go vote them up, everyone ;)